# Pointer in C++ isn't initialized correctly

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to execute the following code, everything is fine except one thing and that is tellerArray[2] is never initialized properly, it always creates problems for me, and I don't why. It creates problem for me: I came to know this fact when I debugged the code multiple times.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stddef.h>

using namespace std;

class Customer {
public:
    void setTime(int time) { this->_time = time; }
    int getTime() { return this->_time; }
    void setNextCustomer(Customer *next) { this->_next = next; }
    Customer* getNextCustomer() { return this->_next;}
private:
    int _time;
    Customer *_next;
};


class Teller {
public:
    Teller();
    ~Teller();
    void addCustomer(Customer *customer);
    int totalCustomers();
    int totalTime();

private:
    Customer *head;
    Customer *tail;
};

Teller::Teller() {
    this->head = NULL;
    this->tail = NULL;
}

Teller::~Teller() {
    delete head;
    delete tail;
    head = NULL;
    tail = NULL;
}

void Teller::addCustomer(Customer *customer) {
    customer->setNextCustomer(NULL);
    if(head == NULL) {
        head = customer;
    } else {
        tail->setNextCustomer(customer);
    }
    tail = customer;
}

int Teller::totalTime() {
    int totalTime = 0;
    Customer *tempCust = new Customer;
    for(tempCust = head; tempCust != NULL; tempCust = tempCust->getNextCustomer()) {
        totalTime += tempCust->getTime();
    }
    return totalTime;
}

int Teller::totalCustomers() {
    int totalCustomers = 0;
    Customer *tempCust = new Customer;
    for(tempCust = head; tempCust != NULL; tempCust = tempCust->getNextCustomer()) {
        totalCustomers += 1;
    }
    return totalCustomers;
}


int getLeast(int, int, int, int);
int getMax(int, int, int, int);


int main(int argc, const char*argv[]) {


    Teller *tellerArray[4];

    // creating four tellers ( counters )
    Teller *tellerOne   = new Teller();
    Teller *tellerTwo   = new Teller();
    Teller *tellerThree = new Teller();
    Teller *tellerFour  = new Teller();

    tellerArray[0] = tellerOne;
    tellerArray[1] = tellerTwo;
    tellerArray[2] = tellerThree;
    tellerArray[3] = tellerFour;

    char wannaBuyAnother = 'n';
    int  duration = 0, minTime = 0, maxTime = 0, index = 0;

    do {
        cout<<"Enter duration of your transaction: ";
        cin>>duration;
        Customer *customer = new Customer;
        customer->setTime(duration);
        minTime = getLeast(     tellerOne->totalTime(),
                                tellerTwo->totalTime(),
                                tellerThree->totalTime(),
                                tellerFour->totalTime()     );

        for(index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
            if( (tellerArray[index]->totalTime()) == minTime ) {
                break;
            }
        }



        tellerArray[index]->addCustomer(customer);

        cout<<"You can stand in Queue "<<index + 1<<"\n";

        cout<<"Do you want to buy another Ticket(Y/N)? ";
        cin>>wannaBuyAnother;

    } while ( wannaBuyAnother == 'y' || wannaBuyAnother == 'Y' );


    cout<<"Number of Customers Deal By Every Teller\n";

    for(index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        cout<<"T"<<index<< "= \t"<<tellerArray[index]->totalCustomers()<<"\n";
    }

    maxTime = getMax( tellerOne->totalTime(),
                            tellerTwo->totalTime(),
                            tellerThree->totalTime(),
                            tellerFour->totalTime()  );
    for(index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        if( (tellerArray[index]->totalTime()) == maxTime ) {
            cout<<"TELLER "<<index+1<<" Deal Maximum Customers of the Day\n";
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}





int getLeast(int first, int second, int third, int fourth) {
    int min = first;
    if( second < min ) {
        min = second;
    } else if ( third < min ) {
        min = third;
    } else if ( fourth < min ) {
        min = fourth;
    }
    return min;
}

int getMax(int first, int second, int third, int fourth) {
    int max = first;
    if( second > max ) {
        max = second;
    } else if ( third > max ) {
        max = third;
    } else if ( fourth > max ) {
        max = fourth;
    }
    return max;
}
```

Here is output when I debug my code.

```
tellerArray[0]  Teller *    0xbffff308  
tellerArray[1]  Teller *    0x8048c64   
tellerArray[2]  Teller *    0x1 
tellerArray[3]  Teller *    0xffff
```

What my code is actually doing is using a linked list ( customer class ) to create a queue ( teller class ) and then based upon the time of each queue, it determines in which queue to put the next customer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The initialisation looks fine.  Those values are odd, but unless you have a specific debug build, you can't always rely on a reported pointer value being correct.  However, it's possible they are being corrupted because of the following undefined behaviour in your program:

I notice that you never initialise the `_next` pointer on `Customer` to NULL, nor to you set it when you add it to the list.  So your list tail always has an undefined `_next` pointer.  This is very likely to give you problems.

You should create a default constructor on `Customer` and initialise `_next` to NULL.

One unrelated thing I will mention is that your `getLeast` and `getMax` functions do not work.  Why don't you try this:

```
cout << getLeast(4, 3, 2, 1) << endl;
cout << getMax(1, 2, 3, 4) << endl;
```

Comment: I've remvoed `else` from the functions `getLeast`and `getMax` and they are working fine. And I've also created **Constructor** to properly initialize the value. Things are fine now.

Answer (score 2):

The code is a bit bizarre, I don't see how the code matches the description of what it is supposed to do.

But bugs aren't hard to find, look at this code

```
int Teller::totalTime() {
    int totalTime = 0;
    Customer *tempCust = new Customer;
    for(tempCust = head; tempCust != NULL; tempCust = tempCust->getNextCustomer()) {
        totalTime += tempCust->getTime();
    }
    return totalTime;
}
```

At no point does your code set a value for `tempCust->_next` so `tempCust->getNextCustomer()` returns a garbage value and so from this point all bets are off, and your code could end up doing anything.

Frankly I can't see any logic to your code so I'm not sure what to do to fix it. At the very least I'd advise to to set _next to NULL in the Customer constructor.

```
class Customer {
public:
    Customer() { this->_next = NULL; }
    ...
private:
    ...
    Customer *_next;
};
```

Comment: My code does set a value for `tempCust->_next` when I invoke the function `Teller::addCustomer(Customer *customer)` except for the tail when I do not set the value of `tempCust->_next`. That was the problem. I followed your instruction to create a **Constructor**.